# Error en carga de datos ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(cadSql);

Tags: java, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo un problema, estoy cargando de la base de datos un usuario que tiene  este código:

```sql
create table usuario
(
  cedula int primary key
  ,nombre varchar(100)
  ,correo varchar(1000)
);
```

Tiene insertado ciertos usuarios y la sentencia de búsqueda funciona correctamente si la pongo directamente en el gestor de la base de datos.

Inserto código de la conexión para ver cual puede ser el error, la conexión es establecida correctamente y los datos son correctos, espero puedan ayudarme, por ahora tengo la función leer los datos de usuario como void para saber si los cargo o no pero eso sera modificado, por ahora necesito es poder cargarme.

```
package Conexion;
import modelo.Usuario;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

  public class ConexionOracle {

     String user;
     String pass;
     String url;
     Connection conex;
     Statement stm;

     public ConexionOracle() {
         user = "system";
         pass = "root";
         url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe";
         conex = null;

     }

     public void conectar() {
         try {
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
             conex = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion realizada");
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se realizo la conexion");
         }
     }
     public void leerDatosUsuarioBD(String cedula){
         String cadSql = "";
         try {
             cadSql = "select * from USUARIO where cedula = "+cedula;
             System.out.println(cadSql);
             ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(cadSql);
             String datos = "";
             System.out.println( rs.getString(1) +" " + rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
             System.out.println( rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getInt(3));
            // return datos;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La tabla no existe");
             //return null;
         }
     }
```

Comment: No has revisado que error se muestra?

Comment: 1º estaria bien saber el mensaje de error para saber exactamente que falla. 2º ejecuta `"select * from USUARIO where cedula = "+cedula` directamente en la base de datos con una cedula valida para asegurarte de que devuelve el objeto usuario.

Comment: Viendo tu código diria que salta un `NullPointerException`  al ejecutar `stm.executeQuery(cadSql);` ya que `stm`es nulo ya que nunca lo inicializas. Te falta un  `stmt = con.createStatement();`

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema principal está en que nunca inicializas `stm` por lo que te va a dar un `NullPointerException`

Prueba a poner un `stmt = con.createStatement();`

```
cadSql = "select * from USUARIO where cedula = "+cedula;
System.out.println(cadSql);
stmt = con.createStatement(); // Esta es linea que tienes que incluir
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(cadSql);
```

Aparte no compruebas si hay resultados por lo que te puede dar otro error los `rs.getString(..)` haz antes un `rs.next()` de la siguiente forma

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // Aqui ya operas con los rs.getString(..) o similares
}
```